# How do you raise an instanced method from a static dependent property in C# similar to VB

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, event-handling, dependency-properties

So I am having a little bit of a problem converting from VB to C# code on a user control that is the base of other user controls.  Specifically event handling on a callback trying to get an instanced method from a static.  So I have this piece of C# for a dependent property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChartData", typeof(ObservableCollection<PlotTrend>), typeof(BaseChart), new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<PlotTrend>(), ChartDataChanged));
public ObservableCollection<PlotTrend> ChartData
{
   get { return (ObservableCollection<PlotTrend>)GetValue(ChartDataProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ChartDataProperty, value); }
}
```

The callback should hookup like so:

```
public static void ChartDataChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var o = (BaseChart)d;

      if ((e.OldValue != null))
      {
        var OldCollection = e.OldValue as ObservableCollection<PlotTrend>;
        OldCollection.CollectionChanged -= o.CalculatePlotTrends;
      }

      if ((e.NewValue != null))
      {
        var NewCollection = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<PlotTrend>;
        NewCollection.CollectionChanged += o.CalculatePlotTrends; 
      }
}
```

So this attempting to reach this:

```
public abstract void CalculatePlotTrends();
```

That then gets to an instanced class inheriting from this base and it will fire on an override method.  Let me be clear this works fine as it should in VB but in C# this subscribing must have subtle differences.  I tried to see what Visual Studio might auto generate and it gives me static delegates, but I need to get an instanced method somehow.  I was using Telerik's Code converter and this was the code that originally worked just fine:

```
Public Shared Sub ChartDataChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim o = DirectCast(d, BaseChart)

    If Not IsNothing(e.OldValue) Then
      Dim OldCollection = TryCast(e.OldValue, ObservableCollection(Of PlotTrend))
      RemoveHandler OldCollection.CollectionChanged, AddressOf o.CalculatePlotTrends
    End If

    If Not IsNothing(e.NewValue) Then
      Dim NewCollection = TryCast(e.NewValue, ObservableCollection(Of PlotTrend))
      AddHandler NewCollection.CollectionChanged, AddressOf o.CalculatePlotTrends
    End If
  End Sub

  Public MustOverride Sub CalculatePlotTrends()
```

Comment: Why are you using 'ObservableCollection' as the type in the C# code, but 'ObservableCollectionContentNotifying' as the type in the VB code?

Comment: I meant to clean that up, that is a custom type that inherits from ObservableCollection that does even more notifications but the base question is still raising the event 'CollectionChanged' that is common for both.  Forgot to remove it to make scope simpler.

Comment: I believe your issue is that the original VB code was written with `Option Strict Off` and VB created a hidden method with the proper signature that called `CalculatePlotTrends`.  Try declaring `CalculatePlotTrends` with the proper signature for an [NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature of the `CalulatePlotTrends` event handler to this:

```
public abstract void CalculatePlotTrends(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e);
```

In C# you must include the parameters in the signature of an event handler.

Comment: Yep, it was just me not remembering my invocation of event handling correctly.  Thanks